# Walking back down Grouse Mountain, after doing the Grouse Grind?

Tags: hiking, vancouver, british-columbia

While I'm in Vancouver next week, I'm (weather permitting) planning to do the [Grouse Grind](http://www.grousemountain.com/grousegrind) hike up Grouse Mountain. Once up at the top there, I expect I'll do a few of the trails around the top, but then there's the question of getting back down...

The normal option, so I understand from the website, is to take the cable car back down the mountain, at a current cost of $10. What I'm wondering is if there are any other options?

I get the impression from the grouse mountain website, and a few other places, that the grind route is supposed to be one way only (up!), so I guess that option is out? Are there any other hiking routes back down instead? And if there are other trails, are they well signed, or will I need to buy a map? (I'll want to get back to somewhere with a bus back to downtown Vancouver, if that affects things)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been planning on doing it, and reading quite a few forums, the Facebook group, and speaking to locals who have done it.  The one thing they all agree on is DO NOT walk back down the Grind. They specifically urge other runners to tell off people walking down, as they get in the way, damage the track as they slip, and on top of that it's brutal on your knees and can easily slip and injure yourself.

I spoke with my roommate and she mentioned the [BCMC Trail](http://www.clubtread.com/routes/Route.aspx?Route=251) and the [Baden-Powell Trail](http://www.clubtread.com/routes/Route.aspx?Route=899), but her understanding is those are also 'technically' one-way (up) and you may also upset people if you go down that, apart from risking your body.

It sounds like the Skyride back down is pretty scenic and recommended.  If you were staying longer you could get the annual pass ($99) but for a once-off, Skyride sounds like the way to go.

[edit] Having now done it, I can confirm that *some* people will turn back at the 1/4 marker, as it's wider and easier and gets steeper after that.  But almost nobody is seen going down after that.  And I can confirm people were telling off the one or two runners who were going back down the trail.  It would certainly damage the trail.